# Select the top m most repeated elements from array in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

Suppose I have an array with `n` elements, some of which may occur more than once.

I want to select the top `m` elements that occur most often in that array.

Can anybody help me with that?

For example, suppose the array is `[1, 3, 2, 3, 5, 2, 2, 3, 6, 8, 9]` with `n=11` elements. If I want to select the top `m=2` of them, those would be `2` and `3`.

What would be the best script to do that?

Comment: Make an array of `{ value: n, count: c }` objects. Sort them by `count`. Then take the first `m` elements.

Comment: What if the result is tied for more than the number you asked for? (E.g. m=3 for your sample array.)

Answer (score 2):

You could create a temporary object to hold the occurrences like `key: count`. Then use the array returned by `Object.keys` to sort the object values. Then `slice` the last "*n*" elements from that array in `.reverse()` order.

Here is an example utility function to get *top* "*n*" *max* occurrences. *Note*: As @n<sup>6</sup> stated above in the comments, this ignores the ties.

***Demo fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/s43k6vsq/***

***Snippet***:

```js
var data1 = [1, 3, 2, 3, 5, 2, 2, 3, 6, 8, 9], 
    data2 = [4, 4, 4, 2, 2, 1, 5, 5, 8, 8, 8, 8, 3], 
    data3 = [3, 23, 23, 45, 54, 54, 54];

// Function parameters = Data Array and top "n" elements to find
function getMax(data, n) {
    var tmp = {}, tops = [];
  
    // Create object with count of occurances of each array element
    data.forEach(function(item) {
        tmp[item] = tmp[item] ? tmp[item]+1 : 1;
    });
  
    // Create an array of the sorted object properties
    tops = Object.keys(tmp).sort(function(a, b) { return tmp[a] - tmp[b] });
  
    // Return last n elements in reverse order
    return tops.slice(-(n)).reverse();
}

// Test with sample data and top "n" 
console.log(getMax(data1, 2));
console.log(getMax(data2, 3));
console.log(getMax(data3, 1));
```

Answer (score 1):

a solution:

```
var arr = [1,2,3,41,11,2,3,4,1];
var sorted = [];

for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    var index = -1;

    for (var j = 0; j < sorted.length; j++) {
        if (sorted[j].val == arr[i]) index = j;
    }

    if (index == -1) {
        sorted.push({val: arr[i], count: 1})
    }

    else {
        sorted[index].count++;
    }

}

console.log(sorted.sort(function(a,b){

if (a.count > b.count) return -1;

if (a.count < b.count) return 1

    return 0

})[0])
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/4nunf753/2/)